# Hello World Multiple Buttons Separate Actions

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development, and haven't programmed GUI's in java yet so button work is all new to me.

I'm making a simple hello world app, has some buttons/radios/checkboxes etc. We have to figure out a way to make it nice, there is nothing specific in the brief. so I figured I'd get some buttons and show the different kinds of toast, maybe change the background etc.

so I implemented a toast based off a tutorial, but it works on all of the instantiated buttons instead of just the one I want. I would like the other button to do something else.

I think it has to do with the onClickListener, but beyond that I'm stuck.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);


        cb=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);
        browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/search");

        }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("MessageDemo").setMessage(
                "This is an Alert Dialogue Toast").setNeutralButton(
                "Here, here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                        Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this,
                                "<clink, clink>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).show();
    }
```

and here's the xml for the buttons

```
 <Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Testa" 
    android:layout_weight="0.2"></Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've added the same onClickListener to each button so they will have the same behavior. You can actually create the listener right inside the setOnClickListener call, like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("MessageDemo").setMessage(
                "This is an Alert Dialogue Toast").setNeutralButton(
                "Here, here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                        Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this,
                            "<clink, clink>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }).show();            
        }
    });

    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something different here.
        }
    });

    // The rest of onCreate
}
```

EDIT: I've updated the answer to make it clear which parts of your original code would go where, but I usually wouldn't stick a big chunk of code like that inside of the `onClick` as it's not very readable. I'd prefer something more like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // other onCreate code
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showBtn1ClickedDialog();
        }
    });
   // other onCreate code
}

private void showBtn1ClickedDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("MessageDemo").setMessage(
        "This is an Alert Dialogue Toast").setNeutralButton(
        "Here, here!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this,"<clink, clink>", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }).show();            
}
```

Comment: Struggling to implement this. Should this be outside of the onCreate?

Comment: No. I'll update my answer to be a little more clear. Anything you put in your previous `onClick` handlers can go inside of these ones. `new AlertDialog... .show();` You will also need to delete the old 'onClick' method and remove the `implements OnClickListener` from the declaration of your Activity class.

Comment: any attempt to use your suggestion just floods the ide with errors. I don't doubt your code, just my ability

Comment: If you'd share the errors, I can probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Think I've got the hang of it now. Thanks very much for your efforts. You too Dave, but I'd like to avoid case-switches for now. This app is supposed to be very basic, I actually can't believe the amount of time I've spent trying to get very simple things to work.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to goto10's solution, if you're not interested in defining the listeners in-line, your existing click handler can check the ID of the view:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.about_button:
            // handle about
            break;
        // etc.
```

I tend towards goto10's solution, or even inner classes, rather than a switch statement like this, but it's another option. That said, I'm voting up his/her answer, and not mine.

One reason to use a `switch` instead of inner classes is memory usage, although with modern devices, this might not be a huge issue--but each inner class *does* take more space, and if the handler is small, IMO is more efficient to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on any button generates an event which is caught by the onClick eventListener. But it doesn't automatically distinguish between the events as to which click generated the event. The information is contained in the **[View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) v** and by using a switch case on the view, we can have separate events for different clicks.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){      
            case R.id.btn1:
                //Do something here
                break;
            case R.id.btn2: 
                //Do something else here
                 break;
            case R.id.btn3:

                 break;
        }   
    }
```

A [summary](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/) of how you can use Listeners in your application.